# com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect

Tags: java, db2, sqldatetime

I'm getting this exception:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect
```

while trying to apply `java.sql.Date` in the format `yyyy-mm-DD` as the value `2011-12-28` in the Java Code.

Comment: what is the code that's causing this exception. Also, people will be more likely to help you if you accept more (than 53%) of the answers provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `PreparedStatement.setDate()` method.

For instance,

```
String date="2011-12-28";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1) VALUES (?)");
ps.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
```